# Travel to UK and planning to take wife

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I am travelling to UK on short term visa for Work (Tier 2),and planning to take wife for 30 days, which visa I need to apply and what supporting documents I will need for it..?

Comment: Might help to tell folks what citizenship your wife holds as that effects what might be required.

Comment: To take your wife? To get a wife while you're there? To borrow someone else's wife? Something else?